# Trying to rotate logs however tee command fails to return after execution

Tags: command-line, sudo, logrotate, tee, null

My logs `nohup.out` is owned by `root` user while I m trying to rotate the logs using `system` which has privileged access using `sudo`

I have written the below script to rotate logs.

cat rotatelog.sh

```
cp /var/www/html/nohup.out /var/www/html/nohup.out_$(date "+%Y.%b.%d-%H.%M.%S");
sudo tee  /var/www/html/nohup.out;
```

The issue is when I run `rotatelog.sh` it does the job but the control does not return to the command line terminal.

i tried `> /var/www/html/nohup.out` but I get `Permission denied` error.

How can I get the logs rotated and return to the command-line?

Comment: What exactly are you expecting `tee` to do here? What provides its standard input?

Comment: `tee` makes the file null which is what i want so it starts logging afresh. i used to use `><log-file>` but i get an error as mentioned in the OP.

Comment: But `tee` will wait for standard input. Does your system provide the `truncate` command?

Comment: `truncate` yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tee` will block waiting for standard input.

If your system provides the `truncate` command, you can try

```
sudo truncate -s 0 /var/www/html/nohup.out
```

Otherwise, you could do something like

```
: | sudo tee  /var/www/html/nohup.out
```

to supply `tee` with an empty stdin.